# Comparing two rows from a csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv, comparison

I am trying to write a manhattan_distance function which would compare two rows from a csv file. I already have a function which reads all the rows from a file but I am unable to access 'row' from this function to use for comparison in the second function. The error I get is "name 'row' not defined". 
Here is my code:

```
def load_from_csv(filename):    
    with open(filename,'r') as csvfile: 
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|') 
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
        return row 

load_from_csv('data.csv') 

def manhattan_distance(x,y):
 return sum(abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(x,y))

print (manhattan_distance(row[1],row[2]))
```

a sample from the csv file (first two rows):

14.23   1.71    2.43    15.6    127 2.8 3.06    0.28    2.29    5.64    1.04    3.92    1065

13.2    1.78    2.14    11.2    100 2.65    2.76    0.26    1.28    4.38    1.05    3.4 1050

Sorry if this is a silly question but I'm not good with Python and I am struggling to find a relevant answer online.

Comment: @kiwi1498 Please look at creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this case, a sample of what the csv contains (maybe the first 5 or 10 lines) would be helpful.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Insert useful output statements to trace the control and data flow. Remove inapplicable code; reduce working code to a hard-coded result. As the posting guidelines say, "make it easy for others to help you."  Most of all, this will show you where you've made your errors.

Comment: thanks, I forgot about that bit, it's there now.

Comment: Row is not set outside of the function. The row variable is only in the memory (scope) of the function. If you use `row = load_from_csv('data.csv')` it will create a variable named row outside of the function which captures the row data from the function.

Comment: Most of all, trace your function usage.  Your function opens the file, reads and prints all of the rows, and returns only the last row.
Your main program then ignores the return value.  You have not stored anything to compare later.  Please work through tutorials on basic data structures and CSV input.

Comment: You will need to provide more detail on the comparison you want to do. such as what fields, what are you comparing etc

Comment: Thank you all, it makes a lot more sense now and I will study the debug blog for future reference :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return a variable that does not exist; `row`

```
for row in reader:
        print(row)
return row
```

You declare `for row in reader` which means you can use `row` within the loop. However, your return statement falls outside of the loop, therefore causing the error that it is not defined.

Try calling your CSV rows to a list and returning the list from the function.

```
def load_from_csv(filename):    
    with open(filename,'r') as csvfile: 
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        data = list(reader)
    return data
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I knew I had to do something along those lines but as I mentioned, I am new to programming so I was not sure how to implement something like this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `row` is only accessible inside your `for` loop. If you want to read all the content of a `csv` you can just do this in your `load_from_csv` function:

```py
def load_from_csv(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
        return [row for row in csv.reader(csvfile)]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
def load_from_csv(filename):    
    with open(filename,'r') as csvfile: 
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

        WHAT_TO_RETURN = [] #an empty list

        for row in reader:
            # print(row) # don't do that

            GET_RID_OF_SPACES = row.split() # this is now a list

            WHAT_TO_RETURN.append(GET_RID_OF_SPACES)

    return WHAT_TO_RETURN 

# this is a list which contains one list for every row in your csv
some_rows_of_data = load_from_csv('data.csv')

def manhattan_distance(x,y):
   return sum(abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(x,y))

my_function_result = manhattan_distance( some_rows_of_data[0],
                                         some_rows_of_data[1] )

print(my_function_result)
```

Something like this should work better.
You cannot `return` something and then not store it when used.
You had `return row` at the end of the `load_from_csv`.

However, when you used `load_from_csv`, you just ran it flat out in the file. You need to **store** the return value in a variable so that you can use it later on.  i.e. `store_it = load_from_csv("somefile.csv")` Now, `row` is `return`ed to `store_it` and saved in a variable.

Of course your `load_from_csv` function has other issues, but most important is to know what to use `return` for, and how to "catch" what is returned.

Happy Pythoning, and Happy New Year.